# Improve the template for Community Ads

Tags: bug, status-completed

The current template for community ads looks like this:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

This is rendered in the preview on page load, and it causes a wasted request to `http://image-url`. Depending on browser timeout settings the loading indicator may last much longer than needed.

Please use a real URL to avoid the impression of overly long load time for that page.

Comment: [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: @bungeshea Bug. As the tag says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed. A placeholder image with a real URL is now included in the post preview.